# How to set the object key value in an angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-forms

I have an object like this.

```
types: {
  2: {
     zoom: true,
     select: true
  },
  4: {
     zoom: true,
     select: true
  },
}
```

Is it possible to create this json object from a angular form?

```
<div formGroupName="types">
    <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="searchType" i18n-placeholder>

    <div [ngModelGroup]="searchType">
        <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="searchType.zoom" color="primary">Zoom</mat-slide-toggle>
        <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="searchType.select" color="primary">Klik</mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sadly it's not possible to change the json but the numbers need to be changable. The form is reactive driven but I could not find a way so I tried template driven but neither way worked out.

Comment: why not using `formControlName`?

Comment: What are those numbers and where to they come from..?

Comment: You want a reactive form, bu you use `ngModel` which is required for Template Driven Forms.

Comment: You can add `property` dynamically to you `object`. but your props name could not be `number` as you mentioned in your example; If you want something its better to have an array of objects. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Angular `reactiveForm` and `Factory` to build your desire `json` object. It is possible to add `property` dynamically to your object. But your props name could not be some numbers as you mentioned in your example; If you want something its better to have an array of objects.

So, try something like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { TypeFactory } from './type.factory.ts';
import { TypeModel } from './app-type.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  typesForm:FormGroup;
  types: TypeModel[] = [];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private typeFactory: TypeFactory,
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.typesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: ['', [Validators.required]],  
      zoom: [''],
      select: ['']
    });
  }

  regForm = () => {
    let newType = this.typeFactory.createTypeDto(this.typesForm.getRawValues());
    this.types = [ ...types, ...newType];
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="typesForm">
  <input formControlName="id" type="number" matInput placeholder="Type" i18n-placeholder>
  <div class="container">
    <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="zoom"  color="primary">Zoom</mat-slide-toggle>
    <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="select"  color="primary">Klik</mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="regForm()">Register</button>
</form>
```

**app-type.model.ts**

```js
export class TypeModel {
  id: number;
  zoom: boolean;
  select: boolean;
}
```

**app.factory.ts**

```js
import { TypeModel } from './app-type.model';

export class TypeFactory {
  createTypeDto(
    form: any,
  ): TypeModel {
    const model = new TypeModel();
    model.id = form.id;
    model.zoom = form.zoom;
    model.select = form.select;

    return model;
  }

}
```